# how do i can split a string with Ascii 255 in C#?

Tags: c#, string, ascii, split

```
var x = Label3.Text;
var y = x.Split('Alt+255');
Label4.Text = y[0];
```

I am having Ascii 255 in the text how can i split in c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ASCII is 7-bit... you aren't dealing with ASCII if the numerical value is greater than 127.

Comment: var y = x.Split('\u00FF');

Comment: Not working is there any standard syntax to do the split with ascii combination numbers

Comment: What exactly do you mean with “Ascii 255”, or “ascii combination numbers”? If you mean “Unicode character number 255”, that is `'\u00FF'`. If you mean “character you write with Alt+255”, that is _usually_ non-breaking space, therefore, try `'\u00A0'`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have commented, ASCII is a 7-bit encoding standard, so there's technically no such thing as ASCII 255. However, I presume that what you're describing is some kind of stream of bytes containing ASCII characters and delimited by byte 255's (0xff in hexadecimal).

Once you've got the data into a string, the individual characters are represented in UTF-16; a multi-byte format that can accommodate the full Unicode character set.

To define a non-printable character literal, you need to use the `\x` escape sequence. So 255 becomes `\x00ff`.

Try this:

```
var y = x.Split('\x00ff');
```

Comment: [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) takes `params char[]`, no need to construct the array manually.

Comment: Sometimes I amaze myself with my inability to see the obvious! Thanks, @Mormegil. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = " ";
            var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(s);
            string binStr = string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2)));
            int decimalEquivalent = Convert.ToInt32(binStr, 2);
            var y = x.Split((char)decimalEquivalent);
```

I did this and it solved myproblems Thanks guys for the Response.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but that looks like a crazy amount of code and complexity to determine a character. Is s really a space, as shown here, or have to used the keypad to enter Alt-255?

Comment: @Steve do u have any standard syntax to get the split function works with Alt-255 or any other Ascii characters

Answer (score -2):

```
string[] splitted = x.Split('+');
```

Comment: Well, Whats your input exactly and whats  your expected output ?